# showModalBottomSheet Performance issue take about 3 seconds to appear

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have several modalBottomSheet in my app to show, most of them have simple widget tree except only one that has 10 DropDownBottom widgets in it

Each one of them load about 200 items, each item is a widget consist of two main widgets a text and an image

when I Press

```
onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: picksWidget, isScrollControlled: true);
      }
```

It take about 3 seconds to open load the modalBottomSheet and it just appear into the emulator without the sliding up animation, other modalBottomSheets in the app load perfectly fine, here is an example of the code I use.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/picked.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/picks.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/Icons.dart';

Widget buildPickerBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
  return Wrap(children: <Widget>[
    PickerList(),
  ]);
}

class PickerList extends StatelessWidget {
  const PickerList({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              AutoSizeText(
                'Pick ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        PickerRow(
          typeOne: 'vr',
          typeTwo: 'er',
          type: 'r',
        ),
        PickerRow(
          typeOne: 'vq',
          typeTwo: 'eq',
          type: 'q',
        ),
        PickerRow(
          typeOne: 'vw',
          typeTwo: 'ew',
          type: 'w',
        ),
        PickerRow(
          typeOne: 'vz',
          typeTwo: 'ez',
          type: 'z',
        ),
        PickerRow(
          typeOne: 'vy',
          typeTwo: 'ey',
          type: 'y',
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Add'),
              onPressed: () async {
                print('added');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class PickerRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String typeOne;
  final String typeTwo;
  final String type;
  PickerRow({@required this.typeOne, @required this.typeTwo, @required this.type});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          DropDownMenu(
            pickType: typeOne,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: 30,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(AppIcons.types[type]),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 2,
            height: 30,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          DropDownMenu(
            pickType: typeTwo,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  //which position will this pick for
  final String pickType;
  DropDownMenu({@required this.pickType});
  @override
  _DropDownMenuState createState() => _DropDownMenuState();
}

class _DropDownMenuState extends State<DropDownMenu> {
  //get a list of the picks to display in the drop down
  static List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDownItems() {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropDownItems = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < Picks.picksNames.length; i++) {
      String pick = Picks.picksNames[i];
      var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage(AppIcons.picks[pick]),
              radius: 15,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 4,
            ),
            AutoSizeText(
              pick,
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        value: pick,
      );
      dropDownItems.add(newItem);
    }
    return dropDownItems;
  }

  var items = getDropDownItems();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String chosenItem = Picked.selection[widget.pickType];
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: chosenItem,
      items: items,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          chosenItem = value;
        });
        Picked.selection[widget.pickType] = value; 
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to development in general so I appreciate if there is any resources on how to measure and improve performance on flutter apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try to load elements before showing the modal...

Comment: @iStornZ can you explain how can I do that?

Comment: you can load all your elements in a Future, then display your modal with all loaded elements on :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `bottomModalSheet` is too heavy. It loads only after the children have completed building.
Resize the images that you use inside the `bottomModalSheet`.

Usually the debug app is very slow compared to the release app.
Generate the apk of the app: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`. 
Install the generated apk `build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk` and see if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid rendering 2000 widgets at once.

First of all look at `ListView` widget and it's `builder()`. Try to refactor your code and put all your items inside this `ListView`. It will increase your performance a lot due to the reason that `ListView.builder()` allows you not to store all your widgets in memory all the time.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html